# Regular expression allowing only characters that will not break a link

Tags: javascript, regex

Anybody can help me with regular expression which will only accept alphabetical letters from English alphabet and numbers without whitespaces ( ÖÜÕÖ and similar characters + whitespaces will break the HTML link this thing is creating )?
I currently have : 
/[A-Za-z ]\S+$/
but this will allow whitespaces and ÖÜÄ and similar at the beggining.

```
function validatenumber(el) {
   var regex = /[A-Za-z ]\S+$/;    
   if( !regex.test(el.value) ) {
      alert('invalid value');
  }else{
          alert('correct value'); 
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qd7BL/1375/ 
Here's a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^\w+$/
```

It'll allow only a non empty string, containing english alphabet letter, both cases, underscore and digits in a string.

Comment: It still says correct value when I put a space as the first or when I put the value something like this öötest

Answer (score 0):

```
 /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

Solved the problem, although I should probably think is more through as much more elements are allowed in link.

Also, the best solution was to use Slugify, a plugin for jQuery which will make the input correct format.

Comment: That's the same as mine except yours doesn't accept `_`. `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.